# how to implement brightness at image in android?

Tags: android, image, effect, brightness

In my application I have a seek bar, by sliding it a user can increase or decrease brightness of image. I have done this work but the problem is that its very slow to show, it takes around 3-4 second to show effect on image after sliding seek bar. Below is my code which I have implemented, can anybody tell me that what should I do to make this effect smooth over an image.

```
public static Bitmap doBrightness(Bitmap src, int value) {
  // image size
  int width = src.getWidth();
  int height = src.getHeight();
  // create output bitmap
  Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
  // color information
  int A, R, G, B;
  int pixel;

  // scan through all pixels
  for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
   for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    // get pixel color
    pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
    A = Color.alpha(pixel);
    R = Color.red(pixel);
    G = Color.green(pixel);
    B = Color.blue(pixel);

    // increase/decrease each channel
    R += value;
    if (R > 255) {
     R = 255;
    } else if (R < 0) {
     R = 0;
    }

    G += value;
    if (G > 255) {
     G = 255;
    } else if (G < 0) {
     G = 0;
    }

    B += value;
    if (B > 255) {
     B = 255;
    } else if (B < 0) {
     B = 0;
    }

    // apply new pixel color to output bitmap
    bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
   }
  }

  // return final image
  return bmOut;
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried creating an AsyncTask to perform these calculations in a different thread? I don't think you should be doing this on the UI thread.

Comment: Yes when I perform AsyncTask to perform this then I have to wait until  my async task perform this, I just wants to make it smooth that a user should not wait while increasing or decreasing brightness

Answer (score 0):

You're walking every pixel in the image in a single thread of Java code as well as using `Color` methods to break down the color into its constituent parts.  This would be a good candidate for something to be done in `RenderScript`.  RS will either offload the operation to a DSP or GPU (if supported on your device) or parallelize it on the CPU.  See [this talk](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1557/a_deep_dive_into_renderscript_andevcon) for basic usage and background on RenderScript.